# TinyMCE : TypeError: this.getDoc(...) is undefined

Tags: tinymce-4

my question seems to be already ask, but truth me the situation here is diferent.

**Problem:**
TypeError: this.getDoc(...) is undefined

**What i already do:**
-update jquery version
-test every parameters pass to the tinymce functions, everything is ok

**My code:**

```
var html = '<div class="traduce-fields"><h4></h4><div class="text-block"><textarea class="textarea-tinymce" id="textarea-' + dataLang + '"></textarea></div><div class="bt-valide-traduce" onclick="sendTraduce($(this))"><p>TO TRADUCE !</p></div></div>';
$('.traduce-bloc-text').find('.traduce-inner').html(html);
//active de nouveau tinyMCE
tinymce.init({selector: '.textarea-tinymce'});
var selector = 'textarea-' + dataLang;
tinymce.get(selector).setContent('ok');
```

Comment: Perhaps you can create a TinyMCE fiddle to show this issue?  Is the issue TinyMCE is not loading?  Is TinyMCE loading but content is not getting loaded via setContent?  Is the `tinymce.get()` call returning something?  Are you sure you are waiting for TinyMCE to be loaded before you try to set content?

Comment: My cod is long but i discoved something that could help you to help me:*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my original comment, my bet is that you are trying to use TinyMCE before its fully initialized.  There is a function that can tell you when its fully initialized so you can use that to set the content:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
        this.setContent('Using the on init stuff!');
    });
}
```

As it takes you time to click on your alert this is probably allowing for TinyMCE to finish loading hence the `setContent()` call is then working.

Answer (score 0):

My cod is long and show him in JS fiddle is hard but I got something that could help you:

This code works:

```
tinymce.init({selector: '.textarea-tinymce'});
alert(tinymce.get(idTextarea));
var tinyMCEInstance = tinymce.get(idTextarea);
tinyMCEInstance.setContent('ok');
```

This not:

```
tinymce.init({selector: '.textarea-tinymce'});
/*alert(tinymce.get(idTextarea));*/
var tinyMCEInstance = tinymce.get(idTextarea);
tinyMCEInstance.setContent('ok');
```

That's very strange, what kind of problem an alert could solve?
Thank you for helping me.